# Compilation error of DropDownList in ASP MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have a view 'Application' which contain a DropDownList like this :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>

<h2>Application</h2>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">

  <h2><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %> </h2>
    <div>         
      <%:Html.Label("Type :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGenre, Model.GenreItems)%>
    </div>
```

I have a compilation error when i try to access to the page of the view :

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.

This is a part of the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Application(Genre genre)
{
    var vv = new FlowViewModel();
    vv.GenreItems = db.Genres.ToList();
    return View(vv);
}
```

and this a part of the model:

```
public class FlowViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public string IDv { get; set; }
    public List<Genre> GenreItems { get; set; }
    public string SelectedGenre { get; set; } 
}
```

***2nd APPROACH :***

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Application(Genre genre)
    {
        var vv = new FlowViewModel();

        vv.GenreItems = new SelectList(db.Genres.ToList(), "ID_G", "ID_G");


        return View(vv);

    }
```

View :

```
<div>         
         <%:Html.Label("Type :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGenre, new SelectList(Model.GenreItems,"ID_G","ID_G")%>

   </div>
```

Model :

```
[NotMapped]
 public SelectList GenreItems { get; set; }
 public string SelectedGenre { get; set; }
```

Error :

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Comment: You don't think it might be important to include the "specific error details"?  You've asked enough of these questions now that you should know what kind of information people need to answer your questions.

Comment: @MystereMan i have resolved this problem now,,but thanks,,,it was a mistake in my database :)

Comment: Then you should post what the problem was, the solution, and mark your own answer as the accepted answer, that way people won't keep trying to solve your problem.  This is only common courtesy.

Comment: yes , i will sorry i am just was busy by resolving the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem of the solution.

I have to create the Controller of the Model Genre and Generate its Views using Entity Framework in order to create the table Genre in the base.

Infact, the source of my problem is db `(private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();)` which is always taken as NULL in the execution because **there is no table Genre in the base.**

So the code of the view is :

```
<div>         
         <%:Html.Label("Type :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGenre, Model.GenreItems)%>

   </div>
```

and the controller :

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Application(Genre genre)
        {
            var vv = new FlowViewModel();

            vv.GenreItems = new SelectList(db.Genres.ToList(), "ID_G", "ID_G");



            return View(vv);

        }
```

and this is the model :

```
public class FlowViewModel
    {

        [Key]
        public string IDv { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public SelectList GenreItems { get; set; }
          public string SelectedGenre { get; set; } 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't DropDownListFor require a SelectList to populate values? I mean how does your drop down list know which property of the Genre object to use for Value and which for Text? You are passing a List but you need to convert that list to a SelectList. This might not be the cause of your bug but it certainly could be...

```
 <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGenre, new SelectList(Model.GenreItems, "ValueFieldName", "TextFieldName"))%>
```

Comment: I already tried that ,,,even i was want to put that in my question as 2nd approach which not successed !

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You already tried the code above and it still doesn't work? You need to post your entire error message then so that we can maybe figure out what's going on...

Comment: this is the error when i put your approach and hold on, i will edit my question and put it as 2nd approach:
(169,10) : error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 169:No mapping specified for properties FlowViewModel.GenreItems in Set FlowViewModels.
An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
 Entity is type [MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel]